# using environment variables in flywayMigrate with intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, flyway

I configured flyway to use environment variables like so

```
flyway.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
flyway.locations=filesystem:db/migrations
```

running `JDBC_DATABASE_URL=... ./gradlew flyMigrate` is working as expected. similarly, `set -a && source dev.env && ./gradlew flyMigrate` is working as expected.

The challange is using Intellij. I've set the environment varables with the command `set -a && source dev.env && idea` When I run the flyMigrate gradle task, it is not able to read the env variables.

However the following code is working as expected

```
public class TestEnv {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
  }
}
```

What am I missing?